# How to send securely a form through twig & symfony?

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm wondering about if exist any method that allows you send data encrypted for example through the view & the controller.
Imagine that you have a TypeForm with the following fields:
[image]

- The user will request a view, the controller will response to the
  user with this view ( a form ).
- The user send his data through the    form
- The userdata will be    processed in the controller and will be stored in the database through the model.

Although your data will be processed in the backend with bcrypt ( for example ). The first request will contain a plain Password without any encryption, that will be transfered from the view to the controller. I'm wondering about which is the best practice working with symfony & twig in order to solve this situation.

For example, HTTPS certificate will encrypt whole channel of communication. There's any tricky that will allow you to do something related to this?

Examples: this could be a TypeForm:

```
    <?php
namespace App\Form;
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Entity\Profile;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\IsTrue;
class RecoveryPasswordType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'first_options'  => array( 'label' => 'Password', 'attr' => array( 'class' => 'form-control repeat', 'placeholder' => 'Password')),
                'second_options' => array( 'label' => 'Repeat Password', 'attr' => array( 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Repeat password')),
            ))
        ;
    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And this cold be the view

```
 {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {{ form_start(form, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-signin disabled'} }) }}
    {{ form_row(form.plainPassword.first, {'label':false}) }}
    {{ form_row(form.plainPassword.second, {'label':false}) }}
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Send</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Kind regards.

Comment: install a (trusted) `SSL` certificate on your webhost - data sent from the client / server will be encrypted for you. No need to do encryption of data yourself on that part. Do note browsers nowadays warn users when typing in sensitive information on a website, e.g. password., without a (trusted) certificate

Comment: Why do you think that securing the controller itself is neccessary? If you want to avoid that the plain password reaches the server after all, you could perform all that hashing stuff in the frontend instead

Comment: @NicoHaase so, what's with the salt. Does the server provide the salt? (you have to ensure it's the same salt). Your approach avoids the server knowing the plain password. Under the assumption, that users may reuse their passwords over and over, this might be a good addon. *However*, an encrypted connection would still be necessary (you effectively replaced the user's password with the user's hash for all intents and purposes).

Comment: Why do you care about the salt? Through an algorithm like bcrypt, the salt is contained within the password hash string itself

Comment: @NicoHaase If you client-side hash, and you send it to the server. On registration it's fine, you could just store the hash. On another login/day though, how does the client know which salt to use? If he uses another salt, it produces another hash.... get my point? Re-Auth becomes a stupid revival of the original problem.

Comment: Ah, okay, got it now. The more interesting question is: what's the key point that the OP is looking for?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm NOT a security expert. But since you're scratching some fundamentals ...

In times of letsencrypt, there's really no excuse for unencrypted connections! (Really! Especially for a login form...). This is the big thing, that symfony can't take care of for you.

The best first line of defence is an encrypted connection. This should prevent anyone from listening on the connection (and passwords send via forms ...)

Protecting the 'plaintext' password, when it reaches your server and finally symfony and your controller, I have to say ... if you don't trust the server, you shouldn't trust anything on it.

If you stay in standard territory with your login/registration form, you shouldn't have any problems. On average, it's the "custom security" done by non-security developers (myself included) that create security risks.

I'm gonna be slightly arrogant and assume, that you're a newbie (no offence intended at all), and advise you to keep it simple, follow the tutorials and thus stay on the safe side. The symfony defaults are very much good enough for the common secure use case.

Also, symfony should usually grab the data and manages the login stuff, so that you can't screw it up. Read up on [how to build a login form](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html). (the "magic" names for the login fields for example).

There are probably also tutorials on how to handle user registration and password changes. (I'd rather trust the tutorials on the symfony page, on average). Registration and password changes are not protected by the same mechanisms that protect the login.

You also write:

> The first request will contain a plain Password without any encryption, that will be transfered from the view to the controller.

First of all: No. No plain passwords will be transferred from the view to the controller. I don't want to go into too much detail, but your view only gets data, that you explicitly provide in your controllers. So it is transferred from the symfony framework, through multiple layers of services that handle security and other fancy stuff*, to the *controller*. Which then can do stuff, it should also create a response - for example by rendering a view - and then return the response (symfony again will push it through some layers of services to the user).

*) if you install bundles/packages that can add event listeners, those bundles/packages can theoretically intercept requests, before the security kicks in. So don't blindly install packages.